# Any Java Proxy Server Library Available?

Tags: java, proxy, reverse-proxy

I'm developing a client application. The application connects through a proxy server that run at 127.0.0.1:1080

The proxy server running at 127.0.0.1:1080 will also forward the client request through a set of random proxies and return the output back to the client application.

Basically the client makes request through a proxy server but the proxy server forward request through a set of random proxies.

Is there a Java library that can help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a quick search, and found the following

Java HTTP Proxy Library - http://sourceforge.net/projects/wpg-proxy/

JAVA SOCKS - http://jsocks.sourceforge.net/

Google Data API - https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/proxy_setup

Answer (score 2):

[Apache HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html) library supports proxies.