# Creating a proxy server with Java

Tags: java, http, proxy

A homework assignment asks me to write a Java program that will act as a proxy server, and handle all outgoing web requests.

My teacher hates me and I have no idea where to begin.

Can anyone offer some pointers, or tools I should look into?

I've been playing with `HttpCore` and `Socket`s but I am not getting too far and I am worried I am wasting my time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your teacher hates you?

Comment: Yes and its quite obvious. But that's for a different forum :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840603/any-java-proxy-server-library-available